# How to count number of columns in between 2 cells

Tags: excel

Is there a way to count columns in between?
E.g. "name" is 3 columns from "height"

```
Defined name
Column A = "NAME"
Column B = "Gender"
Column C = "Height"

-------------------
1 | A | B | C | D |
-------------------
2 |Amy| F |151|N/A|
-------------------
3 |Bob| M |180|   | 
-------------------
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `COLUMN` method. It will return the column number of the reference.

```
Defined name
Column A = "NAME"
Column B = "Gender"
Column C = "Height"

-------------------
1 | A | B | C | D |
-------------------
2 |Amy| F |151|N/A|
-------------------
3 |Bob| M |180|   | 
-------------------
```

I'm assuming you had a typo and you meant `NAME` is two columns away from `HEIGHT`

```
=ABS(COLUMN(A2) - COLUMN(C2)) #=> 2
```

Comment: much for simple that I expected. Thank you very much.